# What do you call a search component that filters data inside a data-table?

Tags: search, filter, data-tables, component

Sometimes when you have a large data-table you want to narrow down the amount of data.

A common approach is to use filters. But, sometimes you're given the option to use a search bar that pretty much act as a filter. When you enter keywords into the search bar you search within the result and everything that doesn't match the search query is (usually) instantly being removed from the table.

Does this search component have a name? Like "Filter search" or "Local search."

Comment: Are you wondering if it's an existing convention among UX'ers? Or, are you looking for something to call it?

Comment: Existing convention if there is one. I want to be able to describe it in our design system just like Tabs, Accordion, Switches, etc.

Comment: Angular's documentation refers to it as a filter: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an industry-wide agreed convention for what it is called, but I would call it a **Contextual search**.

On the [Carbon design system documentation](https://carbondesignsystem.com/components/search/usage/#formatting) by IBM, it's just called a Search.
[image]

I wouldn't call it a filter search, as this screenshot below from [Ant design system](https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-filter-search) explains what a filter search is *(at least to them)*, and this behavior isn't what you described.
[image]

Comment: Yes, a 'filter search' would be searching for a specific filter in this case. Could you define the features that separate your idea of a 'contextual search' from a regular 'search'?

Comment: It seems that there are no clear conventions besides the generic name search. I like Contextual Seach. It is better than just Search. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's just a search.

When you use Google you are filtering a huge list of data relating to websites so that it only shows the results that are relevant to you.

The main difference between a 'modern' search and a filter is that a search tends to be a little more intelligent: you searched for "car" so it will return results for "automobile" too. whereas a filter will simply carve off anything that doesn't match the exact term.

Not all search routines are capable of this distinction so it's best to check with your engineers about the capabilities for 'fuzzy' searches before you commit to a UI choice involving a search.

Comment: I think the difference between a Google search page and this filter search thing is that you narrow down and manipulating the data that you are looking at. Sure, you could argue that you are doing the same thing with Google but it not quite the same ux pattern.

Comment: It can be called Search and Filter. On clicking Filter, Chips of various categories will show up which will narrow down the search results. Filter dropdown can be put beside the search bar to 'search by' as per those categories.

Answer (score 0):

search within results

or

add additional filters